# django-admin migrate can't find module

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-migrations

I'm following [Amazon guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) on deploying a Django app to elastic beanstalk, but I get an error that I could reproduce locally. All the commands were ran locally.

I created a virtualenv with python 3.4, activated it, installed Django and started a project named "django_eb", having the directories like the following

```
django_app
└── django_eb
    ├── django_eb
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    └── manage.py
```

I run

```
django-admin migrate --settings=django_eb.settings
```

and get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/django_app/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/tmp/django_app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/tmp/django_app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/tmp/django_app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/tmp/django_app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/tmp/django_app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/tmp/django_app/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2189, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2189, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2201, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django_eb'
```

Why can't it find the module?

Answer (score 1):

Why can you try "python manage.py migrate".